# How to use type using parametric typing

Tags: julia

I am trying to use type using `parametric typing` But I get an Error. My julia version is 0.6.

Code:

```
type BasicRBC{T <: Real}
    a::T
    b::T
    vce::Matrix{T}
    matrix1::Matrix{T}
    c::T
    output::T
    cons::T
    vG::Vector{T}

end
```

Error:

```
invalid redefinition of constant BasicRBC
```

`a`,`b`,`c`,`output` and `cons` are `Float64`

`matrix1` is `Matrix`

`vG` is `Array`

`vce` is `[ 0.9 0.8 0.1]`

Comment: clear your workspace (e.g. using `workspace()`). You're trying to redefine an existing variable called BasicRBC or something along those lines. If you type the above code in a fresh julia session it works fine.

Comment: I wrote type... above of main function in my program but I got this error. Where should I write this function?

Comment: You cannot modify a type in the same Julia session because Julia compiles things using the information about the exact type layout in order to make functions fast. Thus if you want to change type definitions, you need to refresh your workspace or restart Julia as @TasosPapastylianou said.

Comment: Thank you. how can I chose your answer as a best answer here and close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify a type in the same Julia session because Julia compiles things using the information about the exact type layout in order to make functions fast. Thus if you want to change type definitions, you need to refresh your workspace or restart Julia as @TasosPapastylianou said.– Chris Rackauckas